# Is that question grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Neighbors pooled their resources, planting different kinds of foods and forming
cooperatives.

i think it should have written "planted different kinds of foods and formed cooperatives". what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original sentence, the neighbors performed one action: they pooled their resources. This means that they planted different kinds of foods and formed cooperatives.

A similar sentence to this would be:

> The students decided to collaborate, checking each other's homework and forming study groups.

Your new sentence has the neighbors performing three actions: pooling their resources, planting different kinds of foods, and forming cooperatives.

This is akin to:

> The students decided to collaborate, checked each other's homework, and formed study groups.

"The neighbors pooled their resources" is a complete sentence, as are "the neighbors planted different kinds of foods" and "the neighbors formed cooperatives". However, the first sentence uses the *planting* and *forming* phrases to clarify exactly **how** the neighbors pooled their resources. Thus, the three actions are not of equal importance: the most important part of the sentence is that the neighbors pooled their resources; the rest of it is just to clarify.

As a result, though your new sentence is also grammatically correct, the original sentence is stylistically better (edit: in this context).

Comment: I want to know more about this kind of sentences. Can you suggest me link or grammar website that contains such kind of sentences and their use. Thank you.

Comment: @JeezLouise expresses her opinion about style. It is a personal opinion. If I were editing the text, I would not change either version in favour of the other: they are both clear and they are both idiomatic.

Comment: It depends on the intent of the author. As the author has written the original, I take that to mean that the author is intending to emphasize that the neighbors pooled their resources and that the other two phrases are secondary. I will edit my answer to clarify that I mean stylistically better in this context.